# Third party component with multi-OS/browser instructions for enabling geolocation services?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, components

Is there a third party component that can give the user of a HTML5 web app instructions on how to enable location services on the operating system and browser they are using?

I am using navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) and testing reveal that several iOS users have location services disabled all together. Some have it enabled in general, but disabled for the app Safari or the app Chrome.

I want to give users proper instructions on how to enable it, but the instructions will of course vary depending on operating system and browser. My question is if anybody has made this and offer it as a library or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The best I have so far is a link to google with a pre-specified search query "enable geo location services". This is actually a pretty decent solution, because Google will adapt your search results to your OS and browser.